# Why does this Insert of two distinct values cause a Unique Constraint violation?

Tags: sql-server

Given the following table definition

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  ID bigint IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) not null,
  NativeName nvarchar(150) not null,
  EnglishName nvarchar(150) null,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( ID )
);

ALTER TABLE Test ADD CONSTRAINT UI_Test_NamePair UNIQUE (NativeName, EnglishName);
```

Why do the following statements cause a Unique Constraint violation on the second insert? And is there any way around it?

```
INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县' );
INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县 ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།' );
```

This results in (translated):

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint "UI_Test_NamePair". A duplicate key can not be inserted into the  Test object. The duplicate key value is (桑日县 ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།, Sangri).

Comment: Likely, due to the collation, the characters `ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།` are being ignored for comparison purposes. Using a Binary collation, for example, does not replicate this problem [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f74a5ff55cfd0a5ff6b41f0788d0c93b).

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the issue. My bad.

Comment: It's not a "bad" at all. Collations can be "tricky" at times.

Comment: You should post that as an answer @Larnu. ;)

Comment: Was making a more complete answer for the OP, @EricBrandt :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, this is likely due to the collation you're using. What ever your default collation is, the characters `'ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།'` are being ignored for comparison purposes. For example, forcing the collation to `Latin1_General_CI_AS` [replicates](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c237be4840488a4eb0931da07286497) this error:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  ID bigint IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) not null,
  NativeName nvarchar(150) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  EnglishName nvarchar(150) null,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( ID )
);

ALTER TABLE Test ADD CONSTRAINT UI_Test_NamePair UNIQUE (NativeName, EnglishName);

INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县' );
INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县 ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།' );
```

> Msg 2627 Level 14 State 1 Line 2
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UI_Test_NamePair'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key value is (桑日县 ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།, Sangri).
>   Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 2
>   The statement has been terminated.

One way to solve the problem is to use a different collation, such as a [binary collation](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f74a5ff55cfd0a5ff6b41f0788d0c93b):

```
--Ensure you drop prior test table
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  ID bigint IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) not null,
  NativeName nvarchar(150) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL,
  EnglishName nvarchar(150) null,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( ID )
);

ALTER TABLE Test ADD CONSTRAINT UI_Test_NamePair UNIQUE (NativeName, EnglishName);

INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县' );
INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县 ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།' );
```

Note that as a result, when comparing the values against others columns with your default collation you will likely get collation errors. Therefore, you *might* want to use a [computed column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7db4c2e4bff7ecb5eb57bb4c62e4bb8), and force the collation and index that:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  ID bigint IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) not null,
  NativeName nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
  NativeNameBinCollated AS NativeName COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN PERSISTED,
  EnglishName nvarchar(150) null,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( ID )
);

ALTER TABLE Test ADD CONSTRAINT UI_Test_NamePair UNIQUE (NativeNameBinCollated, EnglishName);

INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县' );
INSERT INTO Test( EnglishName, NativeName ) VALUES ( N'Sangri', N'桑日县 ཟངས་རི་རྫོང་།' );
```